# Asset url is required for uploading the video on Facebook in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

According to `facebookDev.com` we need asset lib but it is depreacted:

[image]

Comment: Screenshots are evil.

Comment: You do not require asset lib. When you are trying to upload any video from iPhone, you pick it from gallery. And to pick it from gallery , you need to use UIImagePickerController, Which will give you "Asset URL" of that selected video.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `asset lib` but it's actually `asset url` that mean you required `asset url(url of video)` to share video on `facebook` from your application. You can get `video url` from `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` of `UIImagePickerController` something like,

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

     NSURL *vidURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

  }
```

Screenshot you posted on your question is also tells that you can get `url` from `UIImagePickerController`. And it is not deprecated!!!